# Extending Identity class to store more data in current session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I currently moving a project from Web Forms to MVC. I encountered on probably simple problem, but I stopped for a while so I need a suggestion so I can move on. I use Identity to authenticate user. But logging is based on user and other data, let's say university. User can be member of different university so unique is: user + university combination. My problem is that I need this data over http context because existing library use it. So now I can:

```
string UserName = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
```

What I need is to have:

```
string University = HttpContext.User.Identity.University;
```

I want to avoid using:

```
Session["University"] = "MIT";
```

Because of security reasons. So is there other alternative?

Comment: I do not believe this is a duplicate, he is asking for extending AspUsers Table Directly, the answer linked is to AspUser `Claims` which is different